# Are there hidden layers in an LSTM network cell aside from the input?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, lstm

For an LSTM cell, we have three type of input: Cell state and hidden state from last cell, input vector for current state input.

Aside from these three input layer that we are certain for the vector size, there are some functional layers contained in LSTM cell: Sigmoid layer, Tanh layer, and some vector operations.

I would like to ask, is there any hidden layer contained within these functional layers?

For example, does sigmoid layer consists of H hidden neurons that would first map the input neurons to another distribution, then apply sigmoid function to do non-linear transformation?

Or does these functional layers like simply apply sigmoid function to the input layer neuron-by-neuron, then produce the output?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: If you simply search with Google for `lstm diagram`, this is [one of the first results](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/).

Comment: Thanks, I have seen this website before, but this is not what I want. I hope for a more detail diagram which contains hidden neurons, input layer, output layer, just like an tradition neural network diagram.

Comment: But the hidden layer is *whatever you want it to be*, just like with any other network type. MLPs? [Sure thing](https://machinelearningmastery.com/stacked-long-short-term-memory-networks/). Convolutional? [Check](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925231217307555). Etc, etc.

Comment: The whole point of that first link you'd already seen was to explain the structure of a single unit in an LSTM, because that's where the architectural difference lies.

Answer (score 0):

I am doubt about your explanation about the weight matrix. In my understanding we are using the below matrix.

```
Input - order n

State / Output - order h

four input  Matrix having order h X h+n

four output matrix having order h X h
```

In the backpropagation, we have to use the below matrix orders

```
output difference delta - order h
```

Please comment if I am wrong in any of the area.